# Android Listview duplicate items after clear

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a problem with duplicate items in a ListView. I read a lot about duplicate entries about it didn't help. It would be realy gret to find a solution.

I cannot reproduce it. One of my customer tells me, that it happens sometimes and sent me a screenshot, but I just don't know why. Here is my code:

```
    public class NewsFragment extends SherlockFragment implements ActionBar.TabListener
    {

    private ArrayAdapter<NewsEntry> adapter;

    private NewsModel model = new NewsModel();
    private Button mFreistellungButton;
    private boolean mMehrNews;

    private ListView mListView;
    private Button mNewsarchivButton;
    private Fragment mFragment;

    private static boolean mNewsAktualisieren = true;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newslistemain, container, false);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newsListView);


        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<NewsEntry>(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_list_row, model.getFirstThreeNews());

        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        mNewsarchiveButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newsarchiveButton);

        mMoreNews = false;
        mNewsarchiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                setMoreNews(!isMoreNews());
                updateNews();
            }

        });
}

public void updateNews()
    {
        adapter.clear();
        if (isMoreNews())
        {
            mNewsarchivButton.setText("show 3 News");
            for (int i = 0; i < model.getNews().size(); i++)
            {
                adapter.add(model.getNews().get(i));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mNewsarchiveButton.setText("Newsarchive");
            for (int i = 0; i < model.getFirstThreeNews().size(); i++)
            {
                adapter.add(model.getFirstThreeNews().get(i));
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that easy solution is to create new adapter when you want to reload it:

```
public void updateNews()
    {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<NewsEntry>(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_list_row, new ArrayList());
        if (isMoreNews())
        {
            mNewsarchivButton.setText("show 3 News");
            for (int i = 0; i < model.getNews().size(); i++)
            {
                adapter.add(model.getNews().get(i));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mNewsarchiveButton.setText("Newsarchive");
            for (int i = 0; i < model.getFirstThreeNews().size(); i++)
            {
                adapter.add(model.getFirstThreeNews().get(i));
            }
        }
this.adapter = adapter;
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

It's hard to find this bug, when you can't reproduce it. But if you will create new adapter you can be sure, that it's not possible to have old elements in it.

But I recommend to override BaseAdapter and implement your own adapter. It very flexible to control elements in it and build custom ui.